# Resize hide/show password button in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

As you can see the size is too big and I want to resize it to a smaller size. Any idea how to do it?

[image: Picture here]

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/password_field"
    android:layout_width="272dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:background="@drawable/email_password_filler"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.208"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    tools:ignore="Autofill,RtlSymmetry,TextFields">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/email_password_filler"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_password"
        android:paddingStart="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:textSize="13sp">

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the size by changing these two parameters.

```
android:layout_width="put value here"
android:layout_height="20dp"
```